# trying to get fbpanel installed but getting confusing errors

Tags: software-installation, python, configure

I'm not too keen on these python errors to figure them out. this is the error I am getting, but I'm using alsa/pulseaudio so I have no idea how to read python errors.

```
%mike@voidz fbpanel-master>>$./configure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./configure", line 502, in <module>
main()
File "./configure", line 489, in main
resolve()
File ".config/options.py", line 64, in resolve
if opt('sound') is None and pkg_exists('alsa', '--atleast-version=1.0.10'):
File "./configure", line 297, in pkg_exists
return sp.call(cmd) == 0
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

all I am getting out of it is this

```
if opt('sound') is None and pkg_exists('alsa', '--atleast-version=1.0.10'):
```

that there is a problem with alsa - I have alsa/
and installed other devel-libs. still getting this error. this is what I have to work with in my repo, stars indecate already installed.

```
%mike@voidz ~>>$sudo xbps-query -Rs alsa
[-] AlsaMixer.app-0.1_3             Simple dockable mixer application for Li...
[-] a2jmidid-8_4                    Daemon for exposing legacy ALSA sequence...
[*] alsa-lib-1.1.0_1                The Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (A...
[*] alsa-lib-devel-1.1.0_1          The Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (A...
[*] alsa-lib-python-1.1.0_1         The Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (A...
[-] alsa-plugins-1.1.0_1            Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA)...
[-] alsa-plugins-ffmpeg-1.1.0_1     Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA)...
[-] alsa-plugins-jack-1.1.0_1       Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA)...
[*] alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-1.1.0_1 Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA)...
[-] alsa-plugins-samplerate-1.1.0_1 Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA)...
[-] alsa-plugins-speex-1.1.0_1      Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA)...
[-] alsa-tools-1.1.0_1              Advanced ALSA tools for certain sound cards
[-] alsa-tools-devel-1.1.0_1        Advanced ALSA tools for certain sound ca...
[-] alsa-utils-1.1.0_1              The Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (A...
[*] apulse-0.1.7_1                  PulseAudio emulation for ALSA
[-] balsa-2.5.2_3                   An email client for GNOME
[-] cava-0.4.0_1                    Console-based Audio Visualizer for ALSA
[-] patchage-1.0.0_1                Modular patch bay for audio and MIDI bas...
[*] python-alsa-1.0.29_1            Official python bindings for ALSA (Python2)
```